# Windows service installer for different user account (other than local system)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-installer, installshield

```
Set objService = objWMIService.Get("Win32_BaseService") 

objService.Create("usb2",  "usb test",  "c:\usb2.exe", 
 OWN_PROCESS,  NORMAL_ERROR_CONTROL,  "Automatic",  NOT_INTERACTIVE,  null
```

This always creates Windows service installation pointing to

> localsystem

user(due to the null), I want to point to something other than localsystem, different user account & password. How do I point to a different user account when I create installer for Windows services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are authoring an MSI using InstallShield based on your tags.  You shouldn't have to write any code.  You can define your service using the  ServiceInstall table.  Create a component with your EXE as the keyfile and then go down under advanced, services and right click to add a new service.  Fill out all the attributes and you should be good to go.